# Getting monthly maximums from hourly data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset composed of tide levels taken every hour for the past 14 years and I am trying to create a new data frame that has the maximum tide value for each month with its associated date.

So I need to get the maximum tide value for each month and the date associated with it.

I got somewhat close to what I wanted but I can tell there is a mistake somewhere.

Here is a sample of the original dataset:
[image: Original]

This is the syntax I used to generate the output:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',errors = 'ignore')
ddf = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = 'Date',freq = 'M')).max()
```

This led me to get this output:
[image: Output]

Everything looked good at first (it's in the correct format) but then I noticed it's just listing the last day of each month so I feel like there is a simple mistake I made somewhere.

I'm new to Python and this is one of my first posts on here so I apologize in advance if I formatted any part of my post incorrectly.

Comment: Can you add your sample and output as text as not as images?
If you could provide your as a [MCVE], I'm sure you'll get an answer in no time.

Comment: It's listing the last date in the 'Date' column.  Is it also listing the Tide value of the last date in the 'Tide' column?

Comment: Is time a separate column, or is it part of the date column?  Try pasting the output of `df.head().to_dict()` to give a better indication of what your data looks like.

Comment: I tried pasting text but it kept messing up the format and making it hard to read so I left the screenshots

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created some sample data to better illustrate what I believe you are trying to do.

You can then use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) to get the index locations of each monthly max `data` value via:

`df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M'))['data'].idxmax()`

Then use `loc` to subset your dataframe on these max monthly values (you could also append with `.set_index('Date')` if you'd like that as the index).

```
np.random.seed(0)
timestamps = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2020-01-01', end='2020-10-01', freq='1h')
data = np.random.randn(len(timestamps))
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': timestamps, 'data': data})

monthly_max_vals = df.groupby(
    pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M'))['data'].idxmax()

>>> df.loc[monthly_max_vals].reset_index(drop=True)
                 Date      data
0 2020-01-21 14:00:00  2.696224
1 2020-02-13 22:00:00  3.170975
2 2020-03-26 20:00:00  2.929096
3 2020-04-05 14:00:00  2.464322
4 2020-05-09 22:00:00  3.801660
5 2020-06-08 10:00:00  2.600672
6 2020-07-23 13:00:00  2.979976
7 2020-08-23 16:00:00  2.841767
8 2020-09-30 17:00:00  2.944984
9 2020-10-01 00:00:00  0.817049
```

Comment: Can I ask why it outputs the daily max? Is there something I can pass that can take the monthly maximums? This got me closer to what I need, I just now need to get the max value for each month and the date associated with it

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were after the daily max values. I've amended it to get the max monthly value for each year with the appropriate date and time when that occurs.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the month frequency (M) uses the end of the month. If you want the beginning of the month, you need month start. (MS)

Example:

```
np.random.seed(0)
timestamps = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2020-01-01', end='2020-10-01', freq='1h')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': timestamps, 'data': np.random.randn(len(timestamps))})
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = 'Date', freq = 'MS')).max()
```

See [this table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) for more information.